# Can I bond my ground to my gas pipes?

Tags: electrical, grounding, grounding-and-bonding

Do I have to install the grounding electrode all the way to the service section, or can I bond the gas pipe to building steel which is continuous through out bldg and then bond the steel to the service?

Comment: Is this gas piping black iron or CSST? Does it feed any appliances that also use electrical power, such as a furnace, power-vented water heater, or electrically ignited range?

Answer (score 1):

Code requires the pipes to be bonded. Building steel can be used as part of the grounding electrode/ conductor so bonding the gas pipe at its entry to bonded building steel is code compliant and even required (that the metal lines likely to be energized be bonded).